# Where do I upload website files onto ec2 lamp stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lamp

On amazon EC2 I've set up my LAMP stack (using a bitnami stack image). I've succesfully connected to it via both SSH and FTP. However, I'm not sure where to upload my .php site files so that they can be viewed by public visitors.

I've tried simply putting them in `home/bitnami/`, and even tried creating a `www` folder in `/var/` to mimic this guide: http://www.comtechies.com/2013/01/how-to-host-dynamic-php-website-on.html#.UgsP5JK2OH2

I always get the screen that says `"Congratulations! You are now running BitNami LAMP Stack 5.4.16-0 in the Cloud."`, even though I've tried conecting from the ec2 server's public dns, from the elasticIP I set up, through `localhost:8888/` and `http://127.0.0.1:8888/`.... but to no avail. If I try to access a specific folder by appending `/index.php` or `/testsite/` to any of the addresses above, I get "Not found".

Am I even supposed to/able to host a .php site on EC2? Ex upload an index.php file onto EC2, have it connect to the MySQL database I have set up (on the same EC2 server), etc?

Comment: *"Am I even supposed to/able to host a .php site on EC2? [...] MySQL database I have set up on the same EC2 server"* -- yes. About the Bitnami instance, sorry, I don't know. I would try to explore the bitnami image and locate the configuration of the Apache server, and determine what the DocumentRoot is from there.

Comment: Alright, thank you Bruno.

Answer (score 0):

According to bitnami wiki it is in /opt/megastack/apps - here you create a folder with your app and apache serves it in a vhost you configure. It's a good practice to check /etc/httpd/ folder for the confifugration files and DocumentRoot.

Note, make sure that you remove the index.html file you find by default in the folder. The index.html has a higher priority in being served than the index.php in the bitnami stack configuration.